# Losing field level information

Tags: custom-field, dml, exception

I'm having an issue where when I perform a dml operation on a sobject list, I lose field level information when catching the dml exception.  Does anyone know a work around for this issue?

Here is a quick example.

```
List<SObject> obj = [SELECT SomeField__c FROM CustomObject__c];

try
{
    update obj;
}
catch (DmlException e)
{
    // catching a field level validation 
    e.getDmlFields(0); //this returns null
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a method that returns a list of Schema.sObjectField's.  You need something to assign it to.  I would use the getDmlFieldNames() method

Try something like this

```
try {
     update obj; 
} catch (DmlException e) { 
     string myFields =  e.getDmlFieldNames(0); 
     system.debug(myFields);
}
```

Here's some documentation to look at as well

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm